# Something is wrong in the first line on text?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to make an automatized twitter bot, and I always get an error saying "Missing ; before statement. (line 1, file "Code")"  Here is my code:

```
package nu.glen.yourpufflebot 

import nu.glen.followbackbot.{
  BeHaveDoKeywordPrefixResponder,
  GerrundKeywordPrefixResponder,
  PastTenseKeywordPrefixResponder
}

class YourPuffleGerrundResponder extends GerrundKeywordPrefixResponder {
  override def combine(gerrund: String, rest: String) = "Your puffle's %s%s".format(gerrund, rest)
}

class YourPufflePastTenseResponder extends PastTenseKeywordPrefixResponder {
  override def combine(verb: String, rest: String) = "Your puffle %s%s".format(verb, rest)
}

class YourPuffleBeHaveDoResponder extends BeHaveDoKeywordPrefixResponder {
  override def combine(verb: String, rest: String) = "Your puffle %s%s".format(verb, rest)
}
```

Comment: Looks fun, but this isn't Javascript. Google Apps Script uses Javascript + their own API for their services.

Answer (score 1):

Thats certainly not javascript which is what apps script uses.